# Multi-Conductor Control Cable

Tags: electrical

If I'm in need of running a 12 conductor, 16-20awg ventilation system control cable and 2 conductors need to be shielded, is it OK to run a single shielded cable?

Comment: What cable does the manufacturer of the ventilation system specify?

Comment: Does this cable need to be multiconductor or multi-pair? What are the two shielded conductors within the cable used for?

Comment: They are the two wires on a Discharge Temperature Control on a make up air unit.  Total control wires is a count of 11

Comment: If you don’t know how these wires are used then give us the model number of the equipment so we can look up the requirements.  This is sounding more commercial than DIY Home Improvement though....

Answer (score 1):

Yes and possibly no. Considering it is an AC control - what lines need to be shielded ? The possibility exists that it will make no difference that they just need to be shielded from the externals (if the instructions call for a 12 conductor cable and tell you two of them need to be shielded - this would be odd - as cable is usually shielded as a bundle or all wires in the cable are shielded individually).

I am of the persuasion that this shielded cable would be acceptable as typically your wire runs internal to the bundling sheath are twisted to cancel out stray induction forces.

Comment: They are the two wires on a Discharge Temperature Control on a make up air unit. Total control wires is a count of 11

Comment: @PBFlyer I think you will be fine. Unless these are actual wires for a temperature sensor - in which case the wires are probably supposed to be shielded thermocouple wire . You have the make/model and all of that information along with instructions etc.. so with out that - this is the most accurate answer I can give you .